# while read loop not ignoring files that don't match pattern that awk is looking for

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop, scripting

From the below file I want to grab only the pattern between the special char '@'. however, I'm ending-up with different.

testfile.txt

```
## START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=@mysite.mw_path@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@mysite.mw_brkr_path@
#
path.mw.site.profiles=@mysite.mw_path@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@mysite.mw_brkr_path@
## END :: end of file ##
```

total 9 lines in text file and my script is test_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  pattern1=$(echo "$line" | awk -F '@|@' '{print $2}')
  echo $pattern1 one
  
      if [ ! -z "$pattern1" ]; then
       echo "pattern is not empty"
      fi
 
done < "$1"
```

the first echo statement I added to test the value in pattern1 variable.

```
raj@my_server ~]$ ./test_script.sh testfile.txt
one
mysite.mw_path one
pattern is not empty
one
mysite.mw_brkr_path one
pattern is not empty
one
mysite.mw_path one
pattern is not empty
one
mysite.mw_brkr_path one
pattern is not empty
one
```

I'm getting the above output, I'm expecting the output like below

```
mysite.mw_path one
pattern is not empty
mysite.mw_brkr_path one
pattern is not empty
mysite.mw_path one
pattern is not empty
mysite.mw_brkr_path one
pattern is not empty
```

appreciate the help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your attempt, I don't understand the idea behind the regular expression `@|@`. It means _an @ or an @_, and could be easier written by `-FS @`.

Answer (score 3):

It's much more reasonable to make just one copy of awk do all the work, instead of running a separate copy of awk for each line of input; you can also make `awk` itself skip the empty lines:

```
while IFS= read -r pattern1; do
  echo "$pattern1 one"
done < <(awk -F@ '$2 != "" {print $2}')
```

...which properly emits:

```
mysite.mw_path one
mysite.mw_brkr_path one
mysite.mw_path one
mysite.mw_brkr_path one
```

The general form of an awk statement is `CONDITION { ACTION }`; when you skip the CONDITION it defaults to operating on every input, and when you skip the ACTION it defaults to `print $0`, but you can always fill both parts out.

Note also that `-F'@|@'` is exactly the same as `-F@`.

Comment: I have another case , here testfile1 and testfile3 are same and  testfile2 has 2 lines 
mysite.mw_path=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
mysite.mw_brkr_path=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/


`while IFS= read -r line; do
  pattern1=$(echo "$line" | awk -F '@|@' '{print $2}')
      if [ -n "$pattern1" ]; then
         pattern2=$(grep "$pattern1" $2 | awk -F"=" '{ print $2 }')
         sed "s|$pattern1|$pattern2|g" testfile3.txt > output_21aug.txt
      fi
done < "$1"
`
test_script.sh testfile1.txt testfile2.txt

sed is working for only 2nd line

Comment: We answer the question you ask. If you have a new and different question, ask it separately.

Answer (score 2):

I consider it overkill to launch an awk child process for each input line. If you want to read the lines within bash, you can also do the extraction in bash. Using your variable names:

```
 if [[ $line =~ @(.*)@ ]]
 then
   pattern1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
   [[ -n $pattern1 ]] && echo pattern is not empty
 else
   echo pattern not found in line "$line"
 fi
```

Comment: how are we passing the file here to read the line?

Comment: Consider fixing your quotes (`echo "pattern not found in line $line"`) -- otherwise a line that contains, say, the string `*.txt` will have that replaced in `echo`'s output with a list of files matching the glob.

Comment: @Rajasekhar : This is something you already have in your original code. I didn't see a reason to copy this, and just posted my variant to calculate `pattern1` from `line`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Right; plus, without quoting, `echo` would condense a run of spaces into a single space. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

To obain the desired output, the below line must be moved inside the `if [ -z "$pattern1" ]; then` block

```
echo $pattern1 one
```

It is encouraged to use `printf` instead of `echo`.

When a variable is used, the shell is performing word splitting. Very often `"${pattern1}"` or `"$pattern1"` are used to prevent this.

`awk` can be used for the whole file (**EDIT**):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash --

while IFS= read -r pattern1 ; do
  if [[ -n "${pattern1}" ]] ; then
    printf "%s one\npattern is not empty\n" "${pattern1}"
  fi
done < <(awk -F '@' '{print $2}' "$1")
```

Comment: Perhaps more bash-like would be `[[ -n $pattern1 ]]` instead of ` [ ! -z "${pattern1}" ]`. But your solution is of course correct as well.

Comment: @user1934428: true, fixed. thx. Charles_Duffy provided the most performant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You neither need a shell script, nor a loop. Simply use `cut`:

```
cut -sd@ -f2 yourfile.txt
```

or with `awk` only:

```
awk -F@ '/@/{print $2}'
```

Output:

```
mysite.mw_path
mysite.mw_brkr_path
mysite.mw_path
mysite.mw_brkr_path
```

---

If you still want to solve the problem with a shell loop, you can do it in shell directly (without spawning `awk` processes every time):

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS=@ read -r _ pattern1 _; do
  if [ -n "$pattern1" ]; then
    echo "$pattern1 one"
    echo "pattern is not empty"
  fi
done < "$1"
```

(and there's no need to run it with `bash`)

Comment: -Thank you for it , please help here , actually the question I asked is subset of this one, 
here is the case , here testfile1 and testfile3 are same and testfile2 has 2 lines(key-value pairs) mysite.mw_path=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/ mysite.mw_brkr_path=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/ 
`while IFS=@ read -r _ pattern1 _; do
  if [ -n "$pattern1" ]; then
     pattern2=$(grep "$pattern1" $2 | awk -F"=" '{ print $2 }')
     sed "s|$pattern1|$pattern2|g" testfile3.txt > output_21aug.txt
  fi
done < "$1" `
test_script.sh testfile1.txt testfile2.txt 
sed is working for only 2nd line

Comment: @Rajasekhar it is impossible to read code posted in comments. Please post a new question if you have a follow-up question (and link the existing one). A shell script might not be the best or easiest solution for your problem. Have you considered a python or perl script instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '
## START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=@mysite.mw_path@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@mysite.mw_brkr_path@
#
path.mw.site.profiles=@mysite.mw_path@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@mysite.mw_brkr_path@
## END :: end of file ##'
```

---

```
awk '_<($!NF = $2)' FS='@'
```

---

```
mysite.mw_path
mysite.mw_brkr_path
mysite.mw_path
mysite.mw_brkr_path
```